# Как настраивать TinyMCE в WP?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

Никак не могу понять, как использовать документацию https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-beta/plugins/table/ в WP, куда вставлять код из примеров?

Answer (score 0):

> куда вставлять код из примеров

В [свой плагин](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) (приоритетно) или в плагины для создания сниппетов (напр [этот](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/)) или в файл функций темы (худший вариант)